# Modification to Ron De Bruins Email Different Files (?)

Tags: email, excel, outlook, vba

I'm using Ron de Bruins code for emailing many different files to different people, as shown below. But the issue I have is, if an email address exists in column B and the corresponding workbook doesn't exist it still creates an email but with no attachment, as there isn't one. Would anyone know how to modify the code so that if a workbook didn't exist it doesn't create the email?

```
Sub Send_Files()
'Working in Excel 2000-2013
'For Tips see: http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winmail/Outlook/tips.htm
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim cell As Range
Dim FileCell As Range
Dim rng As Range

With Application
    .EnableEvents = False
    .ScreenUpdating = False
End With

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For Each cell In sh.Columns("B").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

    'Enter the path/file names in the C:Z column in each row
    Set rng = sh.Cells(cell.Row, 1).Range("C1:Z1")

    If cell.Value Like "?*@?*.?*" And _
       Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) > 0 Then
        Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

        With OutMail
            .to = cell.Value
            .Subject = "Testfile"
            .Body = "Hi " & cell.Offset(0, -1).Value

            For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
                If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
                    If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
                        .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next FileCell

            .Send  'Or use .Display
        End With

        Set OutMail = Nothing
    End If
Next cell

Set OutApp = Nothing
With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: HINT: Before you create the email using `Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)`, check if `FileCell` has any value :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a flag to go to the next item if the file does not exist:

```
   Dim noFile as Boolean

   noFile = True
   For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
     If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
       If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
         noFile = False
         .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
       End If
     End If
   Next FileCell

   if Not noFile then .Send
```

There are other ways to do this (see for example Sidharth Rout's suggestion which checks for the existence of files before even starting to create the email); I chose the above because it minimizes the amount of change needed in your existing code (just three lines, easy to see what they do).

Some people would prefer to invert the logic, with a `hasFile` boolean:

```
   Dim hasFile as Boolean

   hasFile = False
   For Each FileCell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
     If Trim(FileCell) <> "" Then
       If Dir(FileCell.Value) <> "" Then
         hasFile = True
         .Attachments.Add FileCell.Value
       End If
     End If
   Next FileCell

   if hasFile then .Send
```

Comment: +1: Simple additions. Boolean checks are quick and easy for disabling/enabling stuff like this in a jiffy. :)

Comment: Brilliant guys, thanks for the suggestions. And Floris Great breakdown for an answer, much appreciated.